# MySQL statement with if and CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns ID, Name, Floor and Ceiling.  I need to build a select statement that either concats or doesn't the Floor and Ceiling values.  If Floor and Ceiling are the same, then I need to just return Floor, but if they are different I want to concat the columns as a range column.

Here's example data:

```
ID | Name | Floor | Ceiling
---------------------------
1    name1  1       2
2    name2  5       5
3    name3  7       9
```

The statement should return the following:

```
ID | Name | Range
-----------------
1    name1  1-2
2    name2  5
3    name3  7-9
```

Here's my statement so far, what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT name,
(CASE
 WHEN floor != ceiling THEN CONCAT(floor, '-', ceiling) AS range
 ELSE floor AS range
END)
FROM tablename
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. You don't put `AS range` inside the `CASE` expression, you put it at the end.

```
SELECT name,
    CASE
    WHEN floor != ceiling THEN CONCAT(floor, '-', ceiling)
    ELSE floor
    END AS range
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the alias `range` outside the `CASE` clause, like the following:

```
SELECT name,
(CASE
 WHEN floor != ceiling THEN CONCAT(floor, '-', ceiling)
 ELSE floor
END) AS range
FROM tablename;
```